# Good Node JS AES compliant Encrypt Decrypt module

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a Node JS module that encrypts and decrypts strings like the following PHP code do:

```
function encrypt($decrypted) {
    // salt
    $salt = '!mysalthere123456789';
    // Build a 256-bit $key which is a SHA256 hash of $salt and $password.
    $key = hash('SHA256', $salt ."supersecretkey13456789", true);
    // Build $iv and $iv_base64. We use a block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode. (Note: ECB mode is inadequate as IV is not used.)
    srand();
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
    if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22)
        return false;
        // Encrypt $decrypted and an MD5 of $decrypted using $key. MD5 is fine to use here because it's just to verify successful decryption.
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    // We're done!
    return $iv_base64 . $encrypted;
}
```

Basically this returns a random encrypted string even though you keep the same IV and Password (unlike many other encrypt tools that always return the same encrypted string)

I am not a computer expert and thus have no idea how to convert this into Node Js so I am looking for an existing module to assist me with my tiny project.

Does anyone knows of a good one ? I have tested a dozen but they always returned same values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var SALT = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

function encrypt(text, key){
   var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc',SALT + key)
   var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
   crypted += cipher.final('hex');
   return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text, key){
   var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',SALT + key)
   var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8')
   dec += decipher.final('utf8');
   return dec;
}
```